# Joining between multiple databases

Tags: c#, sql, database, inner-join

*Update* I get an Invalid object name error for the DataBaseA.dbo.templates

I wish to Inner join two tables from seperate databases on the same server (Local).

But i can't seem to get it work. Also i don't understand how i should be handling my connectionstring, as i'm currently setting the current connection to the connectionstring of my database. But in this example i'm trying to connect to two different databases in the same query.

This is my SQL code so far:

```
"SELECT a.template.*, b.c_template.* FROM DatabaseA.dbo.templates a INNER JOIN DatabaseB.dbo.c_template b ON a.id = b.template_id"
```

And this is my connectionstrings:

```
<add name="Unit" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseA.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Content" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: You need Database B to be a LINKED SERVER in Database A (assuming you're sending the SQL command to Database A).

Comment: I would suggest placing this join inside a Store Procedure. I haven't tried issuing a join from the application like you are doing but we do this all of the time in a Stored Procedure without any problems.

Comment: How do i link the databases, Tobberoth?

Comment: First of all, make sure you have permissions on both DBs. If you have permission on both DBs, then 1 connectionstring would be enough to execute this query. Optional : Better to havce this query in stored procedure.

Comment: @HardCoreProgrammer: Do i need to specify both databases on the single connectionstring? How would it look like.

Comment: Connectionstring pointing to any one of the databases would be enough.
Provided login should work with both DBs.Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried using only one connectionstring and it returns this error: Invalid object name 'Unit.dbo.templates'. Unit is the name of my DatbaseA

Comment: @Mathias - Do you know If the table "templates" has the schema owner as "dbo" or It is something else. Can you execute the following query and see If you find the table? SELECT * FROM Unit.dbo.templates

Comment: You're right. It can't find Unit.dbo.templates. How do i find the schema owner?

Comment: I was about to say that.. Please try to run plain SELECT Query as Ashish has suggested. I suspect the dbo object is different

Comment: run below script in SSMS
`sp_help YourTableName`
then see what is there under owner column

Comment: @HardCoreProgrammer: It states the schema as dbo :/ I suspect my Connectionstring is wrong then:
<add name="Unit" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseA.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: hmm.. were you able to get the query working without "unit.dbo"

Comment: @HardCoreProgrammer: Yes i can query a single database without the unit.dbo.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know If the table "templates" has the schema owner as "dbo" or It is something else. Can you execute the following query and see If you find the table?

```
SELECT * FROM Unit.dbo.templates.
```

If you don't find the table, you should use the the following command to find out the schema owner:-

```
Use [Unit]
Go
sp_help templates
```

In the below example, the schema owner is dbo. When you execute yours, you would see some other schema owner (e.g xyz). Use that schema owner.

```
SELECT * FROM Unit.xyz.template
```

[image]

If you are still not able to find the table, It sounds like the default database for the query from the application is set to the database where the table "tenplate" does not exist. Can you try using a different form of connection string. "myUsername" in the below connection string should have same required privileges to both DatabaseA And DatabaseB:-

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

Example :-

```
Server=localDB\v11.0;Database=DataBaseA;User Id=UserA;Password=UserAPassword;
```

Create a database user named "UserA" and have appropriate access to both DatabaseA and DatabaseB.

Comment: It states the schema as dbo :/ I suspect my Connectionstring is wrong then: <add name="Unit" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseA.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: How should i implement this, when i'm using a local database?

Answer (score 0):

just use `DatabaseName..TableName`

With this use your joins regularly as you use.

(You have taged it in sql... atleast i know with sql this[`databasename..tablename`] works)

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S. SQL is the generic query language, you are assuming a specific implementation

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yup, i thought it will be nice if it also works with mdb, it will b helpful for him, thats why i posted

Comment: databasename..tablename implies the default schema to be "dbo". You should never assume the schema and should explicitly declare it. e.g. databasename.dbo.tablename.

Comment: Why can't i find DatabaseName.dbo.Tablename though?

Comment: @Mathias - Do you know If the table "templates" has the schema owner as "dbo" or It is something else. Can you execute the following query and see If you find the table? SELECT * FROM Unit.dbo.templates

Comment: You're right. It can't find Unit.dbo.templates. How do i find the schema owner?

Answer (score 0):

That is much more efficient to:

1. Read data from separate databases in different datasets.
2. Use LINQ to join them.

Comment: I am not very familiar with LINQ, so i'd like to see if i can get this to work without it.

Comment: There is several samples with LINQ **join**:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9

Comment: I disagree. If each table has a large number of records, it's far more efficient to perform the join on the server and return the results the client.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below script in the DB to know DB owner

`sp_help YourTableName`

then see what is there under owner column