# Query multiple databases on Local host

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to join two two tables in seperate databases on the same server.
I keep getting the error Invalid object name 'Unit.dbo.templates', as if it can't find my database when it's being queried on the Database name.

Database 1:
Name: Unit
Schema owner: dbo

Database 2:
Name Content
Schema owner: dbo

This is my connectionstring so far:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Unit.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is the query i'm using to test:

```
SELECT * FROM Unit.dbo.templates
```

Is anybody able to see what i am doing wrong?

Comment: what about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193827/joining-between-multiple-databases

Comment: The topic seemed floated, and with no real answer to the problem i figured i would ask a new question based on the information i acheived so far.

Comment: ok then...best luck!!!

Comment: this may prove helpful to you...go through it http://forums.devshed.com/ms-sql-development-95/access-data-accross-multiple-databases-in-one-query-660137.html

Comment: can u see this query?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123359/selecting-2-tables-from-2-different-databases-access?answertab=active#tab-top  try this one also

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S.: The Query is not the problem. I'm getting an error of invalid object name, when i'm trying to query just a single table with DatabaseName.dbo.Table.

Comment: R u using Stored Procedure?

Comment: Can you just try `SELECT * FROM dbo.templates`? Does that work? Maybe try `SELECT db_name()` to ensure you are connected to the database you think you are. Lastly, maybe try `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t WHERE t.TABLE_NAME like '%template%'` to make sure your table is there and under the same `TABLE_SCHEMA` (dbo) that you are expecting to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to load both databases into LocalDB with the 'Database' property specified in each connection string. Otherwise you get a database name generated from the mdf path.

```
string db1connectionString =
    $@"Database=db1;Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\temp\db1_template.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

string db2connectionString =
    $@"Database=db2;Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\temp\db2_template.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

// Loads db1 into localdb. After this, db1 is available to all other databases hosted in localdb.
// Note that you can check what databases you have in localdb by using either VS Server explorer or SSMS to connect to "(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB"
var db1Server = new Server(new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(db1connectionString)));
db1Server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery("select * from db1.dbo.sysobjects");
db1Server.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();

var db2Server = new Server(new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(db2connectionString)));

// Use db2 as required, e.g.

db2Server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery("select * from db2.dbo.CoolTable");
db2Server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery("select * from db1.dbo.TableInDb1");

db2Server.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();

// Entity framework, sprocs, etc. all work, you won't necessarily need to use SMO when working with db2.
```

Tested with VS 2022, SQL Server 2022.